# In Trying to Extend a Simon Dispa Answer for Adding Vertical Spacing at Certain Points in the Index---a Curious Thing Happened

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, vertical-spacing, idxlayout

This post relates to trying to extend Simon Dispa'a answer given in  [Prescribing Certain Vertical Spacing for Idxlayout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623574/prescribing-certain-vertical-spacing-for-idxlayout)

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\newcommand{\beforeheading}{10ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\beforeheadspace}{.3ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\beforesubheadspace}{.2ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

%\renewcommand\item{\vspace*{\beforeheading}\par} % added <<<<<
\renewcommand\subitem{\vspace*{\beforeheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{20pt}} % added <<<<<
\renewcommand\subsubitem{\vspace*{\beforesubheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{30pt}} % added <<<<<

\begin{document}
    \large
    
    Some words.\index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}}
    \index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, To bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}}
    
    More words.\index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!{Be thine to seek the honest gain, No shallow-tinkling fool"! Sound sense finds utterance for itself, Without the critic's rule.}}
    \index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!{If clear your thought, and your intention true, What need to hunt for words with much ado? The trim orations your fine speaker weaves, Crisping light shreds of thought for shallow minds, Are unrefreshing as the foggy winds That whistle through the sapless autumn leaves.}}
    
    A third set of words.\index{VON VON GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}}
        
    \idxlayout{columns=1}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

Now, I would like to set the heading heading (Goethe's Faust) and its subsequent contents a little below where it presently is.

And, trying to mimic Simon Dispa's method, I figured that I would introduce the following into the    preamble:

`\renewcommand\item{\vspace*{\beforeheading}\par} % added <<<<<`

and

`\renewcommand\item{\vspace*{\beforeheading}\par} % added <<<<<` ;

But alas, when I comment out these two commands in the above MWE, nothing happens.

Nevertheless, when I modify the index entries so that the first heading is "GOETHE'S FAUST" and the second one "VON GOETHE"S FAUST" --- **a curious thing happens**--- I get what I am looking for with not effort at all; i.e.,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\newcommand{\beforeheading}{10ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\beforeheadspace}{.3ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\beforesubheadspace}{.2ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

%\renewcommand\item{\vspace*{\beforeheading}\par} % added <<<<<
\renewcommand\subitem{\vspace*{\beforeheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{20pt}} % added <<<<<
\renewcommand\subsubitem{\vspace*{\beforesubheadspace}\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{30pt}} % added <<<<<

\begin{document}
    \large
    
    Some words.\index{GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}}
    \index{GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, To bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}}
    
    More words.\index{GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!{Be thine to seek the honest gain, No shallow-tinkling fool"! Sound sense finds utterance for itself, Without the critic's rule.}}
    \index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!{If clear your thought, and your intention true, What need to hunt for words with much ado? The trim orations your fine speaker weaves, Crisping light shreds of thought for shallow minds, Are unrefreshing as the foggy winds That whistle through the sapless autumn leaves.}}
    
    A third set of words.\index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}}
        
    \idxlayout{columns=1}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

produces what I am looking for---

[image]

QUESTION: (i) *What caused* the second (desirable) occurrence? (ii) How can I produce it all of the time independently from the specific names of the headings?

Comment: @Ulrich Diez Would you be able to modify the code and post it as a working answer? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index entries are sorted alphabetically/lexicographically according to what is written at the left of `@` in the argument of the `\index`-command.

Entries belonging to the same letter/symbol are grouped together.

Groups of entries belonging to one letter/symbol are separated from groups of entries belonging to another letter/symbol by the token `\indexspace`.

I.e, in the .ind-file you get something like

```
\begin{theindex}
[...]
%%% This belongs to "T":
\item Tim, 1
\item Tom, 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\indexspace 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% This belongs to "U":
\item Ulrich, 2
\item Ulysses, 3
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\indexspace 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% This belongs to "V":
\item Vernon, 1
\item Virgil, 7
[...]
\end{theindex}
```

With your first example things are sorted under "VON GOETHE" or "VON VON GOETHE".

Therefore everything belongs to the group of index-entries for the letter/symbol "V" and thus there are no tokens `\indexspace` between the entries.

With your second example some things are sorted under "GOETHE", others are sorted  under "VON GOETHE". Therefore some things end up in the group of those index-entries that belong to the letter/symbol "G" and other things end up in the group of those index-entries that belong to the letter/symbol "V". The group of things sorted under the letter/symbol "G" is separated from the group of things sorted under the letter/symbol "V" by `\indexspace`.
That's why with the second example you see a vertical space between those entries that are sorted under "GOETHE" and thus end up in the group of index-entries belonging to the letter/symbol "G" and those entries that are sorted under "VON GOETHE" and thus end up in the group of index-entries belonging to the letter/symbol "V".

---

I cannot recommend redefining `\item` in the preamble:

The redefinition may affect environments based on `list`/`trivlist` which don't ensure their own definition of `\item`.

Besides this the redefinition of `\item` has no effect on the index as that redefinition is overridden by the `theindex`-environment which in turn is written to the .ind-file whose reading and processing in turn is triggered by `\printindex`. You can check this by adding `\show\item` to the text of an index-entry. This will make it into the .ind-file and display on the terminal/console the meaning which the command `\item` has at the time when LaTeX typesets the index.

---

If you wish vertical skips before all toplevel-index-entries and not just for separating a group of index-entries belonging to one letter/symbol from a group of index-entries belonging to another letter/symbol, the following might probably do the trick:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \large

    Some words.\index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}
    \index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, To bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}
    
    More words.\index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!Be thine to seek the honest gain, No shallow-tinkling fool"! Sound sense finds utterance for itself, Without the critic's rule.}
    \index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!If clear your thought, and your intention true, What need to hunt for words with much ado? The trim orations your fine speaker weaves, Crisping light shreds of thought for shallow minds, Are unrefreshing as the foggy winds That whistle through the sapless autumn leaves.}
    
    A third set of words.\index{VON VON GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}
        
    \idxlayout{columns=1}
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \long\def\indexspace{\par}%
    \@ifdefinable\saved@idxitem{\let\saved@idxitem=\@idxitem}%
    \long\def\@idxitem{\par\vspace{\ila@initsep}\saved@idxitem}%
    \long\def\subitem{\saved@idxitem\hspace*{\ila@subindent}}%
    \long\def\subsubitem{\saved@idxitem\hspace*{\ila@subsubindent}}%
    \makeatother
    \printindex
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

The sorting order is due to the fact that entries that are to be sorted as "VON GOETHE" in the lexicographical order are before entries that are to be sorted as "VON VON GOETHE"

---

This is a variant where you can specify vertical skips before index's item/subitem/subsubitem:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \large

    Some words.\index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}
    \index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, To bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}
    
    More words.\index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!Be thine to seek the honest gain, No shallow-tinkling fool"! Sound sense finds utterance for itself, Without the critic's rule.}
    \index{VON GOETHE@\textbf{VON GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!2@\textbf{\color{red}{Faust}}!If clear your thought, and your intention true, What need to hunt for words with much ado? The trim orations your fine speaker weaves, Crisping light shreds of thought for shallow minds, Are unrefreshing as the foggy winds That whistle through the sapless autumn leaves.}
    
    A third set of words.\index{VON VON GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined Amid his books, shut up from all mankind, And sees the world scarce on a holiday, As through a telescope and far away---}
        
    \idxlayout{columns=1}
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \long\def\indexspace{\par}%
    \@ifdefinable\saved@idxitem{\let\saved@idxitem=\@idxitem}%
    \long\def\@idxitem{\if@nobreak\par\else\par\addvspace{\beforeitem}\fi\saved@idxitem}%
    \long\def\subitem{\if@nobreak\par\else\par\addvspace{\beforesubitem}\fi
                      \setlength{\hangindent}{\ila@hangindent}\hspace*{\ila@subindent}}%
    \long\def\subsubitem{\if@nobreak\par\else\par\addvspace{\beforesubsubitem}\fi
                         \setlength{\hangindent}{\ila@hangindent}\hspace*{\ila@subsubindent}}%
    % Modify these macros for changing vertical skips:
    \newcommand\beforeitem{2\ila@initsep}% <-vertical space before VON GOETHE'S FAUST / GOETHE'S FAUST
    \newcommand\beforesubitem{1\ila@initsep}% <-vertical space before WAGNER / FAUST
    \newcommand\beforesubsubitem{0.5\ila@initsep}% <-vertical space before quotes and page numbers
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \makeatother
    \printindex
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: @mlchristians You are welcome. "The world, we are often told, is unthankful; I have never yet discovered that it was unthankful, if one knew how, in the proper way, to do it service." Goethe: Wilhelm Meister’s Apprenticeship - [Book I, Chapter XVI](https://www.bartleby.com/314/116.html)   ;-))

Comment: "The finished man, you know, is difficult to please; a growing mind will ever show you gratitude." ---Faust 1, lines 182-3.